# How to write data from SQL Server database to formatted Excel file using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, winforms

I can write data from a SQL Server table into an Excel file and save it anywhere I want. I want to upgrade it by read formatted Excel file in `C:\Format\Sample.xlsx` which has 3 sheets: 1st sheet is the layout that I will fill with data in the 2nd sheet then export. Is it possible to write data into 2nd sheet, keep the 1st sheet then export?

Here my current source code:

```
 clsComboData cdSelectedItem = (clsComboData)cboMatRecv.SelectedItem;
        string PhaseNo = cdSelectedItem.ValueData;
        string RecvPlanDt = dtpMatRecv.Value.ToString();
        string strSQL = null;
        string data = null;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int ci = 0;

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        strSQL =  "SELECT dbo.M_MAT.*, dbo.RecvPlan.*, dbo.RecvPlan.RecvPlanDt AS Expr1, dbo.RecvPlan.STNO AS Expr2, dbo.M_MAT.MatType AS Expr3 "
                + "FROM   dbo.M_MAT INNER JOIN dbo.RecvPlan ON dbo.M_MAT.MatID = dbo.RecvPlan.MatID "
                + "WHERE (dbo.RecvPlan.RecvPlanDt = CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + RecvPlanDt + "', 102)) AND (dbo.RecvPlan.STNO = '"+ PhaseNo + "') AND (dbo.M_MAT.MatType = 0)";

        clsCommFunc.gobjdb.SetSql(strSQL);
        clsCommFunc.gobjdb.ExecuteReader();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        clsCommFunc.gobjdb.Fill(ds);
        //Header export
        for (ci = 0; ci < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; ci++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, ci + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[ci].ColumnName;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, ci + 1].Font.Bold = true;
        }
        //Data export
        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
            }
        }

        System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
        saveDlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        saveDlg.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        saveDlg.FilterIndex = 0;
        saveDlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveDlg.Title = "Export Excel File To";
        if (saveDlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = saveDlg.FileName;
            xlWorkBook.SaveCopyAs(path);
            xlWorkBook.Saved = true;
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
        }

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created");
```